# Fixed navigation: is not fixed on scroll down

Tags: css, navigation

i'm working on this website http://sds-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/en

As you can see, when you scroll down, the fixed navigation and the logo are not fixed in position into the header. How can i solve it?

Comment: The `ul` in the header is pushing down the logo, you need to style it so that your `ul` isn't the full width

Comment: @SamWillis mmh this works for the logo but not for the navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
header#header.scrolled {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

use this